# Having at one's disposal

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests

> One has at one's disposal ...

Is the following an acceptable synonymous phrase?

> One has (the) disposal of ...

It made sense to me initially, if a little more active than the first. But I've now said it so many times it's starting to sound right, wrong, and not like words at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the implications of "at my disposal"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21394/what-are-the-implications-of-at-my-disposal)

Comment: Disagree. I (already) read that just in case, but it asks what the phrase means. I know what it means, I'm just trying to say it differently.

Comment: Well, you won't find reference to [*has the disposal of*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+the+disposal+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20the%20disposal%20of%3B%2Cc0) there, because it's been an archaic form for a century or more.

Comment: My whole question was whether it was synonymous, so the answer was "yes", not "here's a link where that phrase isn't". As for being archaic.. well, I'm a 19 year old native BE speaker and it came naturally to me, so.. make of that what you will!

Comment: But I bet you don't often use the word "disposal" in casual speech anyway (or "one" as the "impersonal pronoun" either). Grammatically there's nothing wrong with "having the disposal" of something, so your instincts are not wrong. It's just that you'll probably notice over time that nobody else says it.

Comment: I would very rarely say 'one' in casual speech (this is written), but I fail to see the issue with 'disposal'. What would you say instead? Even 'use of' isn't quite the same.

Comment: "We have 12 members of staff at our disposal, and only work for eight, so some will have to be sent home." sounds perfectly natural to me, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure that example really works. The fact of the matter is having *something at your disposal* really does mean *have [free and unfettered] access to and **use of** something*. Just as we don't normally *have the disposal* of something today, we wouldn't normally use "disposal" in contexts where we've *already started using them* (i.e. - they've actually come to work). I think I would either simply discard "at our disposal" in your example, or replace it with something like *"here"* (or perhaps *"who have turned up ready and willing to work for us"*).

Comment: Okay, I have never heard someone say "we have these people who have turned up ready and willing to work for us". I have on the other hand, heard 'at our disposal' in this and other contexts. It's nothing like as archaic as you claim.

Comment: I don't think you're quite following what I'm saying. There's nothing "archaic" about having things *at your disposal* - it's just a bit formal, so you wouldn't encounter it often in everyday speech. And *having the disposal of them* is no longer in common use, even in formal written contexts. My point re your example is that you wouldn't normally speak of having *things/people at your disposal* (optional, if you want to use them) when what you really mean is *things/people that you are **obliged** to "deal with" one way or another*.

Comment: IMO, and in my experience, if you keep the phrase "at our disposal" intact, it's perfectly natural in your example.  If you try to reword it, I don't think it would be understood since "at (our/your/his) disposal" is quite idiomatic.

Comment: ^ That's a good answer, that was exactly what I was worried about - it "made sense" to me, but I wasn't sure if it "sounded right", if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to *at one's disposal* and depending on context, consider *avail (oneself) of*.

> One can *avail oneself of*...

[**avail (oneself) of**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avail): make use of; take advantage of.

Comment: I suppose 'available' comes from being able to avail?

Comment: @OllieFord Yes. Does it fit in the context?

Comment: Honestly, it was so long ago I don't remember what the context was!

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these are common in modern usage:

> One has disposal of ...
>
> One has the disposal of ...

The common ways to phrase this almost always take the form "[noun] has at [possessive pronoun] disposal". Some examples:

> One has at one's disposal ...
>
> One has at their disposal ...
>
> He has at his disposal ...

The word at play, here, is obviously "disposal":

> disposal — power or right to dispose of a thing; control: "left at his disposal."

You could, in theory, say "one has the disposal of" but I've never heard it this way and would be tempted to correct someone who used it in that manner. It sounds bad to my ear.

Comment: Albeit not nearly as bad as "me ear" ;)

Comment: @OllieFord: Heh, fixed. :)

Comment: It's an old legal term; _disposal_ is one power that an owner may have, or not, depending. _At `x`'s disposal_ is semantically parallel to _in `x`'s power_ or _under `x`'s control_. Consequently there are expressions like _have the power of_, _have the control of_, or _have the disposal of_. The last one seems to have fallen off the table, however, except perhaps among lawyers.